# how to use find-if with a predicate that takes an argument

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am a beginner learning Common Lisp on my own. Suppose we have a list
`((1 20)(2 30)(5 40))`.
Given the value `2` we want our function to search in the list and return 
`(2 30)`. Or if given the value `5` it should return `(5 40)`. You get the point.
Usually we could have used a predicate like

```
(defun isIndexp (n point)
  (eq n (car point)))
```

to return T or NIL for the find function. But the problem is how to pass an argument to the predicate `isIndexp`? I tried passing an argument `n` to the predicate function `isIndexp` of `find` but the code throws some errors because `isIndexp` supposed to have 2 arguments. I don't know how to tell `find` that the second argument for `isIndexp` going to be an element of `points`.

```
(defun isIndexPresent (n points)
  (find (isIndexp n) points))
```

`mapcar` could have been possibly used to convert the list into another list of `(1 2 5)` and then find the position of the element `2` and then use that position to extract `(2 30)` from our original list. But I wonder if it could be simply done using the `find-if` function.

Comment: Why are you using `find-if` and not `find` with the `:key` argument?

Comment: Your list looks like an association list, why don't you use `assoc`?

Comment: Ok thanks for the quick response. Don't know how to use `find` with `:key` argument in detail. Will see how it works and try it out. Yes it is an association list, yes `assoc` might work. Let me try that too.

Comment: It seems like I had some misunderstanding while understanding `find` function. Both of the approaches you suggest worked. Thanks!

Comment: Please look at the standard naming conventions.  Since the reader internally by default upcases all names, camel case makes no sense in Common Lisp (you actually named your function `ISINDEXPRESENT`).  Standard is to use hyphens, as in `index-present-p`.

Comment: Ok I read them thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a lambda-expression to create the predicate you want:

```
(defun isIndexPresent (n points)
  (find-if (lambda (x) (isIndexp n x))
           points))
```

You can also use `find` with the `:key` option:

```
(defun isIndexPresent (n points)
  (find n points :key #'car))
```

Or, since your `points` list is an association list, you can use:

```
(defun isIndexPresent (n points)
  (assoc n points))
```

Comment: The lambda-expression approach is quite new to me. Haven't studied that yet. But seems interesting. The other two approaches are straight forward and I should have thought of them. Thanks!

Comment: @Svante I reverted your edit. I know the normal CL naming style, but I kept my answer consistent with the names in the question. If you want to post a comment about naming conventions, feel free, but it's not an appropriate use of editing.

Comment: @Barmar: I find it inappropriate not to correct the style.

Comment: @Svante I suggest you read the meta questions about what is appropriate for edits versus comments.